# Shared Preferences, check box, Kotlin, Android

Tags: android, kotlin, checkbox, android-activity, sharedpreferences

I am developing an app that have two different splash screens, and I choose which one is displayed with the following code.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        supportActionBar?.hide()
        val sharedPref: SharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val shared = sharedPref.getBoolean(getString(R.string.splash_key), false)

        if(shared == true) {
            Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
                // Your Code
                val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, SplashScreen::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }, 0)
        }else {
            Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
                // Your Code
                val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, SplashScreenComplete::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }, 0)
        }
    }
}
```

I have created a shared preferences initializing it at false.

Now I have in another activity the following checkbox

```
fun onCheckboxClicked(view: View) {
        if (view is CheckBox) {


            when (view.id) {
                R.id.checkbox_SplashScreen -> {
                    if ( == true) {
                        //Normal SplashScreen
                        Constants.SpashScreenIsEnabled = false
                        val toast = Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Splash Screen Activated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        toast.show()
                    } else {
                        //Small Splashscreen
                        Constants.SpashScreenIsEnabled = true
                        val toast = Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Splash Screen Deactivated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        toast.show()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I take the shared preferences from the main activity to this one to verify if the value is true or not, and clicking on the check box saving the preferences so I can disable the splashscreen?

Comment: You can pass the value in the intent before starting the other activity, like `intent.putExtra("sharedValue", shared)`

Comment: Why are you using `postDelayed` with 0 delay? You can just call your code directly.

Comment: Thats not the problem here, and I am using postdelayed in 0 to debug and not wait for animations everytime I want to test

Comment: Based on your comment on the other question, we need to see how your SettingFragment is set up.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this might be helpful.

set `putExtra` of shared object in `MainActivity`

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        supportActionBar?.hide()
        val sharedPref: SharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val shared = sharedPref.getBoolean(getString(R.string.splash_key), false)

        if(shared == true) {
            Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
                // Your Code
                val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, SplashScreen::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("shared", true)
                startActivity(intent)
            }, 0)
        }else {
            Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
                // Your Code
                val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, SplashScreenComplete::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("shared", false)
                startActivity(intent)
            }, 0)
        }
    }
}
```

Now get it to your another activity like this.

**Note : Choose condition whisly.** I set default condition as true.

```
fun onCheckboxClicked(view: View) {
        if (view is CheckBox) {
            val shared = intent.getBooleanExtra("shared", true)
            when (view.id) {
                R.id.checkbox_SplashScreen -> {
                    if (shared == true) {
                        //Normal SplashScreen
                        Constants.SpashScreenIsEnabled = false
                        val toast = Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Splash Screen Activated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        toast.show()
                    } else {
                        //Small Splashscreen
                        Constants.SpashScreenIsEnabled = true
                        val toast = Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Splash Screen Deactivated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        toast.show()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I Hope this will help you.

Comment: I understand what you have done, but is not what I need.

Comment: I have 4 diferent activities, MainActivity, SettingsActivity, NoSplashScreenActivity and SplashScreenActivity. When the app starts he launches MainActivity, this one  send it to SplashScreenActivity and the app runs normally. Since the SplashScreen is to big, I have a CheckBox on SettingsActivity that is supposed to change the MainActivity to choose NoSplashScreenActivity instead. And I want to store that in shared preferences so the user can disable the splashScreen in his phone.

Comment: Okay.. you can make static variable for Switch and Use anywhere Activity wise.

Comment: Cool, How can I do that exatly?